Delay printing chunk output in Quarto revealjs by `code-line-numbers`
In a Quarto revealjs document, I would like to reveal some code sequentially, and then print the result at the end but only show the result once I've highlighted the line that prints the output.
Here's an example:
---
format: revealjs
---

## A slide

```{r}
#| code-line-numbers: "1|2|3"
#| echo: true
x = 3
y = 9
x
```

If you run the above and then start clicking through the slide, the value of x is displayed on the screen the entire time you're on the slide. Instead, I would like it to show up only when I arrive at the final call to print x.
Possible?
Thanks!

Never mind: I came up with a decent solution.
## A slide

```{r}
#| code-line-numbers: "1|2|3"
#| echo: true
#| results: false
x = 3
y = 9
x
```

. . .

```{r}
#| echo: false

x
```

It would be nice to be able to do this in one chunk, though...
